# How to paramaterize a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Given the following tables

```
mysql> describe customers;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| customer_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| login       | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(32) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| address     | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact     | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)  

mysql> describe orders;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| customer_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| order_id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| order_timeStamp | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| item            | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| price           | double      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I want to get all rows of orders which match a parameterized query (my code will pass in customer_id), plus the customer name from the customers table.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables, and put the condition in the `WHERE` clause at the end of the query:

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,  
  o.order_timestamp,
  o.item,
  o.price,
  c.name,
  c.address,
  c.contact
FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Customers AS c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE o.customer_id = ?
```

Comment: That seems to be returning 0 rows.

Comment: @Mawg - Does it always return 0 rows? Have you tried it without the condition in the `WHERE` clause? Try it with a number directly `WHERE o.customer_id = 2` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Your answer was perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: @Mawg No problem, happens all the times :) You're welcome any time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select orders.*, customers.name
from orders, customers
where orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
and customers.customer_id='MY_ID';
```

Comment: That seems to be returning 0 rows.

Comment: @Magw: have you replaced 'MY_ID' with your id?